# Passing Common Functions through Global Context In Node Red Dataflows

Tags: node-red

There are multiple data-flows in our application configured through Node Red. There are some common functions like date/currency formatting which are used across the flows such as below.

```
function formatCurrencyValues(value, isoCurrencyCode, lang){
    return new Intl.NumberFormat(lang, { style: 'currency', currency: isoCurrencyCode, currencyDisplay: 'code'}).format(value);
}

function formatDate(locale,date){
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale).format(date);
}
```

Is it possible to define these functions at a global level and call them wherever required?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can define functions in the `settings.js` under the `functionGlobalContext` section,

```js
   ...
   functionGlobalContext: {
        formatCurrencyValues: function (value, isoCurrencyCode, lang){
            return new Intl.NumberFormat(lang, { style: 'currency', currency: isoCurrencyCode, currencyDisplay: 'code'}).format(value);
        },
        formatDate: function(locale,date){
           return new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale).format(date);
        }

    },
    ...
```

And use them as follows:

```
var formatCurrencyValues = global.get('formatCurrencyValues')

var foo = formatCurrencyValue(msg.payload, 'GBP', 'en-gb')
```

Comment: Thanks hardillb. Let me explore further.

Answer (score 1):

In a [node-red project](https://github.com/msillano/tuyaDAEMON/wiki/tuyaDAEMOM-global.alldevices#implementation-notes), with many flows, I use the following method to create global singleton objects and function libraries (see also https://discourse.nodered.org/t/is-it-okay-to-use-global-javascript-functions/1306/2). Example:

```
foo{
  value = 3;
  getValue = function() {return this.value};
  }
```

I set in global context the 'data' part only at the start (e.g. in 'On start' or using a 'config node'):

```
   `global.set("foo",{"value"=3});`
```

Then I put the 'function code':

```
   context.global.foo = global.get("foo");
   context.global.foo.getValue = function() {
        return this.value};
```

USE in any function-node:

```
let bar = context.global.foo.getValue();
```

Advantages:

- No external files, no 'settings file' updates.
- `foo` is accessible by any function-node and any flow.
- `foo` is visible in global 'context data' debug pad.
- The function code is easily debuggable.

Hoping this will help.

m.s.